# Password EditText not working in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dialog

Adding an EditText to a dialog and setting its input type to password is not working. Letters stay as plain lettering.

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            EditText txtUsername = new EditText(this);
            txtUsername.Hint = "Username";
            layout.AddView(txtUsername);

            EditText txtPassword = new EditText(this);
            txtPassword.Hint = "Password";
            txtPassword.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword;
            layout.AddView(txtPassword);

            var alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.SetTitle("Login");
            alert.SetView(layout);
            alert.SetPositiveButton("Submit", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                var username = txtUsername.Text;
                var password = txtPassword.Text;

            });
            alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {

            });
            Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
            dialog.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtPassword.InputType =
Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "IsPassword" property.

```
txtPassword.IsPassword = true;
```

Comment: IsPassword is not a property of EditText.

Comment: My mistake. In xamarin.forms you would use an Entry which does have an IsPassword property.